# How to run NServiceBus handler from VS 2008 .Net 3.5 project

Tags: nservicebus

There is NServiceBus handler run on .net 4.0. I need to start it from VS 2008 project with 3.5 runtime (more specifically from SSIS 2008). The message to be send to the handler is parameter-less. What I tried:

- I can not use NServiceBus API because of different .net versions, just can not add reference to the newer runtime library.
- My other idea was to use NServicebus Gateway, but it turned out to be too difficult to run (xml+jsonp+get protocol with bunch of params) and lack of documentation.
- Then I tried to send MSMQ message, but it did not work as well, because NServiceBus requires it to has special caption and extension message area which I can not specify, and it would be not reliable enough even if I could.

Are any other ideas on how to run simple parameter-less handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 2.6 version of NServiceBus which supports .net 3.5 - available here: http://www.nservicebus.com/Downloads.aspx

Comment: My NServiceBus handler already implemented in 4.0 and uses some latest features of the library, I hope I did not mean rebuild my application. Do you mean to use this 2.6 version for API just to run newer version handler like Bus.Send, right? No conflicts expected?